# HTML Select Menu issue in IE11

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have this html for an select control

```html
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1: 1" >Jr.</option>
    <option value="2: 2">Sr.</option>
    <option value="3: 3">I</option>
    <option value="4: 4">II</option>
    <option value="5: 5">III</option>
</select>
```

It is getting rendered as expected in chrome

**chrome image 1**
[image]

**chrome image 2**

[image]

but in IE, the select option is hiding the control when it is clicked or in other words the the select option is not getting opened from the bottom of the select control as seen in this following screen shot

**IE image 1**
[image]

**IE image 2**

[image]

is this a default behaviour or can I change it? I tried giving using this css but did not work

```
   select.form-control {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 325px;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: .01px;
    text-overflow: '';
    position: relative;
}
   option, select.form-control option {
    color: blue !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

any suggestion?

Comment: share your whole code

Comment: It appears you have some CSS package that enhances the styling on your elements. This is greatly important to include in order to recreate the problem you're having as it's highly likely that it's the reason of your error.

Comment: @Johan i have updated my question, please havev a look

Comment: With a little bit of javascript you can simulate a select box and style it any way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard behavior. Every browser renders elements slightly different and has their own styles for it. Some styles can be changed, others are hidden in the shadow root of the elements and cannot be changed. option sadly has only a few styles like color that can be set...

One solution for this would be to hide the select element and control it via another element that can be styled (e.g. span) and JavaScript. That is not really pretty but many css frameworks already do so and if you absolutely have to make it look good (most of the times that is the case) that is your only option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of a custom built select box. As you can see, even putting images in the options is possible now. Hope this helps you.

Fontawesome is used for the caret. Documentation in the JS source code.

```js
// Create a reference to the select box
const selectBox = document.getElementById("selected");
// Add an event listener to detect the click and make the options (in)visible
selectBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Add or remove class 'open'
  document.getElementById("options").classList.toggle("open");
});

// Put all options in an array
const options = [...document.getElementsByClassName("option")];
// Add event listener for each option
options.map( option => option.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Create a reference to the input field
  const myInput = document.getElementById("sel");
  // Retrieve the text from the clicked option
  const optionText = this.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;
  // Put the text in the input field value
  myInput.value = optionText;
  // Put the text in the select box
  selectBox.innerHTML = optionText;
  // Close the select box
  document.getElementById("options").classList.toggle("open")
}));
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 25%;
}

#selected {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  min-width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

#selected:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
}

#options {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#options.open {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li>img {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="sel">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="selected">Select an option</div>
    <ul id="options">
      <li class="option"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/00ff00"><span>Option 1</span></li>
      <li class="option"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/ff0000"><span>Option 2</span></li>
      <li class="option"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/0000ff"><span>Option 3</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i am using angular and the template for the dropdown is already set to the SELECT control now we cannot change it

Comment: can anyone help me with the select control on how to render the option menu at the end of the select control, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can correct the behavior with CSS

```css
select {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1: 1" >Jr.</option>
<option value="2: 2">Sr.</option>
<option value="3: 3">I</option>
<option value="4: 4">II</option>
<option value="5: 5">III</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is possible? Tested with IE11 and the problem is still there...

Comment: which version are you using.. I tried with in IE with correct result.

Comment: @karthickj25 i am using IE11